# How to avoid page break in dompdf

Tags: css, codeigniter, dompdf

I am displaying some question answers in my pdf. But in some cases, the question s on one page and answer will come to the next page. I want to avoid that situation. I want to display question and answer in same page either in first page or next page. I have tried the `CSS` as below:

```
.questiontext
{
  unbreakable: true
}
```

But it is not working for me. Please help me.i added pdf helper and view page as below.

```
$d_arr=date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$location_name="test"       
$list_content=$this->generate_form_list($submission_id,$client_id); 


        $filename_proposalpdf="formname.pdf";
        $this->load->helper(array('dompdf', 'file'));
        pdf_create_proposal($list_content,$filename_proposalpdf,true);
```

in generate formlist i added view page as below:

```
public function generate_form_list($id,$client_id)
{
    $data['form_data']=$this->Mobile_app_model->get_form_list($id,$client_id);
    $data['client_data']=$this->Mobile_app_model->get_client_data($client_id);
    $data['client_idsss']=$client_id;
    return $this->load->view('pdf_formlist',$data,true);
}
```

In view page just i have displayed the data as below:

```
<?php
foreach($task_data as $fdata)
{ 
  echo '<p class="questiontext">';echo $fdata['question_text'];echo '</p>';
  echo '<p id="lableanswer">';echo $fdata['answer'];echo '</p>';echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Please help me how to make both are in one page.

Comment: can you show us your code? view and controller are you converting HTML to pdf?

Comment: try page-break-inside: avoid

Answer (score 11):

The `unbreakable` property is used to prevent line breaks, not page breaks.

What you're looking for is:

```
.question 
{
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

You can find more detailed reference in this [External reference](https://tympanus.net/codrops/css_reference/page-break-inside/)

Addressing your comment below, the problem is that you need to wrap both the question and the answer within a single element styled with `page-break-inside: avoid;`

```
.dontsplit
{
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}

<?php
foreach($task_data as $fdata)
{
  echo '<div class="dontsplit">'; 
  echo '<p class="questiontext">';echo $fdata['question_text'];echo '</p>';
  echo '<p id="lableanswer">';echo $fdata['answer'];echo '</p>';echo '<br/>';
  echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

If you style the `dontsplit` class with `page-break-inside: avoid;` you'll get the whole question-answer block to remain together avoiding page breaks.

Comment: I tried above. It is not working. I am displaying images below question. it is coming as question is in above page and image is below page.

Comment: Just noticed you added some code to you original question. The "trick" is that `page-break-inside` applies to a single element with the class `.question`. I see that the question and answers have different classes, so this won't work. You'd need to wrap both the question and answers in a single parent class (e.g. `.questionanswerblock`.. each "child" can have its own styles, remember CSS cascades) and style that class with the `page-break-inside: avoid;` for this to work (as in that case the parent class would prevent the whole question-answer pair to remain on the same page

Comment: @user9456654 added code suggestion addressing your followup comment.